# Button Mash game

Tags: python

I want to create a game where the idea is to spam as much as possible in the time limit: 10 seconds

```
import time
import random
print("Spamming race")
print("*************")
time.sleep(10)
print("You must spam the number '1'.")
time.sleep(3)
print("Ready")
time.sleep(1)
print("Set")
no = (0.25,0.5,0.7,1,1.25,1.5,1.7,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3)
number = random.choice(no)
time.sleep(number)
print("Go!")

max_time = 1
t = 31
start_time = time.time()
g = input()

if time.time - start_time > max_time > t:      #where the problem is but I don't know why
    distance = g.count('1')
    print("And he crosses the line with a distance of ",distance)
```

It says the problem is on line 23 but I can't see what is the problem can someone help me?

Comment: You forgot to call `time.time`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rawing pointed out, you forget to call `time.time`:

```
if time.time()-start_time>max_time>t:
     distance=g.count('1')
     print("And he crosses the line with a distance of ",distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rawing is correct. To elaborate, use time.time() instead of time.time
I think what you want for that line is:

if (time.time()-start_time)>t: